# Codeigniter Form Validation: Where to set rules?

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation

I'm trying to achieve the "skinny controller", "fat view" and "fat model" structure. However, I am constantly obstructed by the form_validation library.

If that controller deals with a form that has 2-3 fields, it isn't too bad.

But when I have 10 fields, things starts to get really long.
Then I start making callbacks, setting form_error messages, my controller just reaches hundreds of lines.

Is there a general practice on where to set the rules? In another controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to put them in config files as it is described [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#savingtoconfig) I found it hard to work with (I just put the rules in the controller and close my eyes), but maybe it suites you needs.